# Object values returning undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOwDV.png)I am using quotes API to fetch quotes and display them, i can print the object that returns the entire info about the quote but i cant access the individual values of it when i try to use them it just prints undefined in the console log

I expected to get individual values of objects when it called them for example result.content.
Here is the code

```
const url = "https://quotes15.p.rapidapi.com/quotes/random/";
const options = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "api_key",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "quotes15.p.rapidapi.com",
  },
};
(async function main() {
  // You can use await inside this function block
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    const result = await response.text();
    console.log(result);
    console.log(result.name);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
```

Comment: `result` will be a **String** - which doesn't have a `.name` property

Comment: I think you might be use await response.json(). Your response type is json()

Comment: @Kangseohyun yes that was the problem, i fixed it thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

1. You're parsing the response as `text` when you should be parsing as `json`.
2. Your parsed object doesn't have a `name` property. It *does* have an `originator` property which has a `name` property.

Your code will work if you make those changes, and you'll also be able to access the rest of the data in a similar manner.

```
const response = await fetch(url, options);
const result = await response.json();
console.log(result);
console.log(result.originator.name);
```

Comment: Thank you so much that was exactly the problem, its my first time working with APIs so i was having a hard time.